# Search for the username and change the password in the space-separated file using python

Tags: python

The code below reads the files and stores it to an array:

```
import sys
import logging

def file_to_array():
    file_info="/application/files/Password.txt"
    with open (file_info,'rt') ass fh:
        pw_lines = [x.strip() for x in fh.readlines() if not x.startswith('#')] #ignore comments 
    passwd = find_in_pwfile(pw_lines=pw_lines, key1="", key2="DBFS_USR")
     
def main():   
  file_to_array()
```

File:

```
 * DB_USR    ABCDEF 
 * DB_MGR    QWERTY
```

New File:

```
 * DB_USR    PQRSTU 
 * DB_MGR QWERTY
```

I am looking to change the password of `DB_USR` from `ABCDEF` to new password `PQRSTU` in the file.

So I am finding the username in the code using below code. The below code deals with different patterns of entries in the file:

```
def find_in_pwfile(pw_lines, key1, key2)
    patterns = ['^{k1}\s'+{k2}\s+(\S+)\s*$.format(k1=key1 , k2=key2),
                '^\*\s'+{k2}\s+(\S+)\s*$.format( k2=key2),
                '^{k1}\s'+\*\s+(\S+)\s*$.format(k1=key1)  
               ].  #These are various patterns in password file
    for pattern in patterns:
        for line in pwlines
            m = re.match(pattern, line)
            if m is not None
                s= "PQRSTU"
                replaced_line=m.group(0).replace(m.group(1),s)
                return m.group(1)
 #if we reach this point no match has been found
 reach 'NotFound'
```

Now, I would like to change the password in the array and copy the entire array to a file and take backup original file, but I am struck here.
Can you please let me know what's the best approach and how do I go ahead with changing the value in file?

Comment: @triplee . that post is not relevant to my qn actually. really surprised to see this qn has been closed ,  here am talking about replacing a variable and the copying it back to array and then creating a file.Please look into this qn again

Comment: You have an array and you want to write it to the file. Right? Or do you also need help figuring out how to use `re.sub`? We have duplicates for that, too.

Comment: (Refactoring the multiple regexes to a single one would probably simplify your task; it doesn't seem too complex, but it would help if you could explain why you have multiple regular expressions.)

Comment: the multiple regular expressions are used as the file contains these 3 patterns . My goal (assuming its good approach ) 
1. Store File data in array 
2. Traverse the array and find user name
3. Chnage the passord of username in array
4. Finally create a file with the array details (it contains everything from old file and latest updated value)

Comment: Your question only asks about replacing one string; is your regex trying to also validate that every line in the file obeys one of these patterns?

Comment: If you need help with both 3. and 4. you need two different questions. I have added a second duplicate which explains how to use `re.sub` (however, it's more efficient if you combine 2. and 3. into a single loop).

Comment: I Just edited the code with below, but this is not replacing the actual value in list, though replaced line is printing right stuff, its not reflecting in array
               s= "PQRSTU"
                replaced_line=m.group(0).replace(m.group(1),s)

Comment: You are not doing anything with `replaced_line`. You'll want to edit the list itself, or perhaps refactor the code to avoid using a global variable for the list, and have your function `return` the modified list.

Comment: please suggest , i have already found a way to write array to a file , 
The only point where iam struck is to replace the line in array , i have also done the regex substitution too

Comment: `pw_lines = [re.sub(r'^(\s*DBFS_USR\S+)\s+', r'\1PQRSTU', line) for line in pw_lines]`

Comment: Sure , but wiith this , we dont need match function that i have wriiten as we are directly searching dor DBFS_USER, Isnt it ?

Comment: Yeah, this bypasses the function entirely. Like I said, the different regexes can be combined into a single one if you insist on checking all of these patterns separately; the function seems to be designed for a different use case originally.

Comment: you are right , DBFS_USR is just for my testing purpose , i may have to chnage the pwd for other users also and original file consists on 100 usernames and pwds

Comment: Also , pw_lines = [re.sub(r'^(\s*DBFS_USR\S+)\s+', r'\1PQRSTU', line) for line in pw_lines]. is not replacing the password
i tried creating new file like this  after above line:
with open("output.txt", "w") as txt_file:
    for line in pw_lines:
        txt_file.write("".join(line) + "\n")

Comment: Your question is ambiguous in that it shows you searching for `DBFS_USR` but the file actually containing `DB_USR`. If your file really has an asterisk at the beginning of each line, the regex needs an update. Demo: https://ideone.com/1U9PVf

Comment: Oops, also need to switch `\s` for `\S` and vice versa. Sorry, I was thinking of `\w` which has roughly the opposite semantics.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253443/discussion-between-learningcpp-and-tripleee).